# In python, how does the following AutoVivification class work?

Tags: python, dictionary, autovivification

In searching for a way of working with nested dictionaries, I found the following code posted by [nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17160/nosklo), which I would like to have explained, please.

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

Testing:

```
a = AutoVivification()

a[1][2][3] = 4
a[1][3][3] = 5
a[1][2]['test'] = 6

print a
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: {'test': 6, 3: 4}, 3: {3: 5}}}
```

I'm a pretty newbie programmer.  I have learned most of what I know on my own time on the side, with my only formal training being on Turbo Pascal back in high school.  I understand and am able to use classes in simple ways, such as using `__init__`, class methods, and storing data within instances of the class with `foo.man = 'choo'`.

I have no idea how the series of square brackets get directed, correctly, through the class (I presume they are calling `__getitem__` somehow) and don't understand how they each get handled so concisely without having to call the method three times individually.

I was under the impression that the `(dict)` in the class declaration would be handled by an `__init__`.

I've used `try: except:` before, though again, in quite simple ways.  It looks to me like the `try`, when it runs, is calling a series of function `__getitem__`.  I gather that if the current level's dictionary exists, the try will pass and go to the next dictionary.  The `except`, I gather, runs when there's a `KeyError` but I haven't seen `self` used like that before.  `Self`'s being treated like a dictionary while I thought `self` was an instance of `class AutoVivification`... is it both?  I have never assigned twice in a row like this `foo = man = choo` but suspect that `value` is pointing to `self[item]` while `self[item]` points to the result of `type(self)`.  But `type(self)` would return something like this: `<class '__main__.AutoVivification'>` wouldn't it?  I have no idea what the extra round brackets at the end there are for.  Because I don't know how the function is being called, I don't understand where `value` is being returned.

Sorry for all the questions!  There is so much in this that I don't understand and I don't know where to look it up short of reading through the documentation for hours in which I'd retain very little.  This code looks like it'll serve my purposes but I want to understand it before using it.

In case you want to know what I'm trying to do in my program with nested dictionaries: I'm trying to hold map data on an astronomical scale.  While I can't create dictionaries/lists of 10^6 items nested 4 times (that would be 10^24 items!), the space is mostly empty so I can leave the empty values out completely and only assign when there's something there.  What was stumping me was an efficient way of handling the dictionaries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Line by line:

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
```

We make a subclass of `dict`, so `AutoVivification` is a kind of `dict`, with some local changes.

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
```

The [`__getitem()__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) is called whenever someone tries to access an item on the instance through `[...]` index lookups. So whenever someone does `object[somekey]`, `type(object).__getitem__(object, somekey)` is called.

We'll skip the `try` for a moment, next line is:

```
 return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
```

This calls the *unbound* method `__getitem__()`, and passes in our own instance to it, together with the key. In other words, we call the *original* `__getitem__` as defined by our parent class `dict`.

Now, we all know what happens if there is no `item` key in a dictionary, a `KeyError` is raised. This is where the `try:`, `except KeyError` combo comes in:

```
    try:
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
    except KeyError:
        value = self[item] = type(self)()
        return value
```

So, if the current instance (which is a sub-type of `dict`) doesn't have a given key, it'll catch the `KeyError` exception the original `dict.__getitem__()` method throws, and instead we create a *new* value, store that in `self[item]` and return that value.

Now, remember that `self` is a (subclass) of `dict`, so it's a dictionary. It thus can assign new values (for which it'll use the [`__setitem__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), incidentially), and in this case it creates a *new* instance of the same type as `self`. That's another `dict` subclass.

So what happens in detail when we call `a[1][2][3] = 4`? Python goes through this step by step:

1. `a[1]` leads to `type(a).__getitem__(a, 1)`. The custom `__getitem__` method of `AutoVivification` catches the `KeyError`, creates a *new* instance of `AutoVivification`, stores that under the key `1` and returns it.
2. `a[1]` returned an empty `AutoVivification` instance. The next item access `[2]` is called on that object, and we repeat what happened in step 1; there is a `KeyError`, a new instance of `AutoVivification` is created, stored under the `2` key, and that new instance is returned to the caller.
3. `a[1][2]` returned an empty `AutoVivification` instance. The next item access `[3]` is called on that object, and we repeat what happened in step 1 (and in step 2). There is a `KeyError`, a new instance of `AutoVivification` is created, stored under the `3` key, and that new instance is returned to the caller.
4. `a[1][2][3]` returned an empty `AutoVivification` instance. Now we store a new value in that instance, `4`.

Once you go to your next line of code, `a[1][3][3] = 5`, the top-level `AutoVivification` instance already has a `1` key, and the `return dict.__getitem__(self, item)` line will return the corresponding value, which happens to be the `AutoVivification` instance created in step one above.

From there, the `[3]` item access call will create a new `AutoVivification` instance again (because the object at `a[1]` only has a `2` key), and we go through all the same steps again.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`object.__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) documentation, for a start.

The `class AutoVivification(dict)` declaration makes `AutoVivification` a subclass of `dict`, so it behaves the same was as `dict` would unless it explicitly overrides some behavior--as this class does when it overrides `__getitem__`.

The call to `dict.__getitem__(self, item)` would typically be written instead as:

```
super(AutoVivification, self).__getitem__(item)
```

(At least in Python 2.x; Python 3 has better syntax.) Either way, what this does is try letting the default `dict` behavior run, but implement a fallback in case that doesn't work.

`type(self)()` first looks up the class object corresponding to the `self` instance, and then calls the class object--which in this case is the same as writing `AutoVivification()`, which should look much more familiar.

Hope that clears it up for you!